# Android Design Support Library crashes app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Some days ago I switched from eclipse to Android Studio.
Now I have been trying to implement some of the features introduced with the *Android Design Support Library*. But something isn't working.

After a few hours I found out that as soon as I add the following dependency my app stops working:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I haven't changed anything other than that - no layouts or views from the library are used yet.
LogCat only says:

```
ActivityManager: Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{..}    
AndroidRuntime: Shutting down vm
```

There is no exception or warning. But the app isn't responding anymore. If I remove the dependency everything is fine again.

Is there anything I have to take care of while using the *Android Support Design Library*?

Comment: Set the logcat to No Filter and Error and paste the stacktrace.

Comment: I already checked the different LogCat options. There is no exception.

Comment: have u checked  compileSdkVersion and  buildToolsVersion??